How to determine Height and Width of image in Firebase Storage
I'm trying to determine the height and width of images that are stored in Firebase storage using a cloud function. Cloud function that goes through all the image docs in firestore and looks at the image URL to determine the naturalHeight and naturalWidth.
exports.imageHeightWidth = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const imagesCollection = await firestore.collection("images").get();
  const imageDocs = imagesCollection.docs;

  for (const image of imageDocs) {
    const imageDoc = image.data();

    const imageLink = imageDoc.imageURL;

    console.log("imageLink: ", imageLink);
    const height = imageLink.naturalHeight;
    const width = imageLink.naturalWidth;

    console.log("image Dimensions: ", height, width);
  }

  res.send("Hello");
});

I end up getting undefined dimensions:

image Dimensions:  undefined undefined

The closest question was this one but i don't follow how the height and width is found.

An image does not have a naturalHeight or naturalWidth.  Those properties are only applicable to an image in a HTML document. I think you need: Get the width and height of an image in node.js

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of a document that exists inside the "images" collection. Please respond using @AlexMamo
